# Setting a column equal to a value when an ID does not exist in the other table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

*****Added Clarification*****
I have two tables: Lets say I have one that is called "V" that is in my sql database and has a column as "Active" and another table called "S" which has matching columns to V except for the "Active" column. V has more records because it has archived records as well (hence the reason for an active/unactive column). They join on an "ID" field. I need a statement that will change the active column in "V" to 0 from 1 if its ID does not exist in "S"

---

Say I have two tables in a SQL Server database that I am checking against each other to ensure they match. One table has an outside data connection that gets refreshed daily.

I am joining them on an `ID` column, but if the existing table in the database (i.e the one not getting refreshed) has an `ID` that does not exist in the refreshed table, I would like to make set the column `Active` to `1`.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I would suggest that `LEFT JOIN` would appear to be a significant part of what you need.

Comment: It helps people to answer if you supply a [mcve].

Comment: Through the magic of intuition I THINK I know what you're asking (and as @GordonLinoff said, `LEFT JOIN` seems to be part of the answer). But keep in mind we also need to know what table `Active` is in.

Comment: I have two tables: Lets say I have one that is called "V" that is in my sql database and has a column as "Active" and another table called "S" which has matching columns to V except for the "Active" column. V has more records because it has archived records as well (hence the reason for an active/unactive column). They join on an "ID" field. I need a statement that will change the active column in "V" to 0 from 1 if its ID does not exist in "S"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem and it is quite simple:
UPDATE V 
SET Active = 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM S
WHERE V.ID = S.ID)